# SAS ODS tagsets.excelxp: autofit column widths calling vbscript within SAS

Tags: excel, vbscript, sas, vba

Every week I output a `yyyymmdd_report.xls` workbook consisting of multiple sheets with my macro date in the filename. If I open this workbook manually, the following vbs script works fine to autofit the columns:

```
Sub AutoFitAll() 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Dim wkSt As String 
    Dim wkBk As Worksheet 
    wkSt = ActiveSheet.Name 
    For Each wkBk In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
        On Error Resume Next 
        wkBk.Activate 
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit 
    Next wkBk 
    Sheets(wkSt).Select 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True      
End Sub
```

Is there any way I can put this into some sort of call within SAS to where I do not have to do this manually? Documentation I've found online seems a little too complex for my needs. The logic would be:

```
1. Point to/open output report .xls file (maybe some command/DDE method?)
2. Run vbs script above
3. Re-save the file
```

I'm running SAS v9.4 and have MSOffice 2010.

Comment: Try this: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi25/25/cc/25p098.pdf

Comment: Thanks, @RobertSoszyński. The paper doesn't exactly say how `Macro1` is stored or what exactly it is -- I'm assuming it would contain a similar macro as mine above. Would I save the text in a `.vbs` file and call it? That's where I'm confused.

Comment: Depending on how complex your report is, look at ODS Excel that could implement it automatically and avoid this step.

Comment: @Reeza, how is this implemented automatically? The SAS support page for ODS EXCEL at http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/odsug/69832/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p09n5pw9ol0897n1qe04zeur27rv.htm does not mention autofitting columns.

Comment: Post some code that generates an Excel file with issues and I'll see if it can be  modified or fixed using ODS Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of a bummer that the Spreadsheet Markup Language [doesn't support autofit on text columns](https://communities.sas.com/t5/ODS-and-Base-Reporting/How-to-autofix-cell-width-with-ExcelXP-tagset/td-p/9983). But, I think this may fit nicely with your specific situation:

Save the code below to `autofit.vbs`

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
Set xlmodule = objworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1) 

strCode = _
"Sub AutoFitAll() "                                 & vbCr & _
"    Application.ScreenUpdating = False "           & vbCr & _
"    Dim wkSt As String "                           & vbCr & _
"    Dim wkBk As Worksheet "                        & vbCr & _
"    wkSt = ActiveSheet.Name "                      & vbCr & _
"    For Each wkBk In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets"    & vbCr & _
"        On Error Resume Next "                     & vbCr & _
"        wkBk.Activate "                            & vbCr & _
"        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit "               & vbCr & _
"    Next wkBk "                                    & vbCr & _
"    Sheets(wkSt).Select "                          & vbCr & _
"    Application.ScreenUpdating = True"             & vbCr & _
"End Sub"

xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode

objExcel.Run "AutoFitAll"

objworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove xlmodule

objWorkbook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(0) , -4143
objExcel.Quit
```

This will open an Excel file, add the macro, run the macro, remove the macro, and finally save the document as a proper XLS (no warning prompt like when opening an XML file with an XLS extension).

Then leverage this VBScript in an `x` command within your SAS program like so:

```
ods tagsets.ExcelXP file="C:\test.xls";
    proc print data=sashelp.Cars;
    run;
ods tagsets.ExcelXP close;

options xwait;
x "C:\autofit.vbs ""C:\test.xls""";
```

Comment: THIS is exactly what I was looking for! I should note I had to go into Excel and File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings... -> Macro Settings and select Trust access to the VBA project object model. This does the trick, thanks a million @Hugs!

Comment: @Foxer, Awesome! Good thinking, I forgot about that prerequisite.

Comment: Can the vbs interact with the workbook directly? (Without adding a vba macro in the workbook and executing that?)

Answer (score 0):

```
options noxwait noxsync;

/* run Excel, also you can run it manually */
x '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE"';

/* wait, Excel is starting */
data _null_;
   rc = sleep(5);
run;

/* create a connection between SAS and Excel */
filename cmds dde 'excel|system';

data _null_;
   file cmds;
   /* open a file with a macro */
   put '[open("C:\MyMacro.xlsm")]';
   /* run the macro MyMacro in MyMacro file */
   put '[run("MyMacro.xlsm!MyMacro")]';
   /* close the macro file */
   put '[close(0)]';
   /* quit Excel */
   put '[quit()]';
run;
```

In your Excel VBA file (MyMacro.xlsm) you should define a macro which contains information what you want to do on a specific or active workbook.

For example:

```
Sub MyMacro()
  Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Zeszyt1.xlsx"
  Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 100
  ActiveWorkbook.Save
  ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```